# FilterSet for ManyToMany relationship existence

Tags: django-filter

Basic models:

```py
class ModelA(Model):
    name = CharField(...)


class ModelB(Model):
    model_a = ManyToManyField(ModelA, blank=True)
```

```py
class ModelBFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    unassigned = BooleanFilter(field_name='model_a', lookup_expr='isnull')

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ['unassigned']
```

How do I filter (*with `django-filter`*) to find the `ModelB`'s that do not have a corresponding related model?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that what you have should work. Perhaps the `fields = ['unassigned']` is unnecessary? According to [the documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tips.html#filtering-by-empty-values) you can also negate the filter thusly:

```
class ModelBFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    assigned = BooleanFilter(field_name='model_a', lookup_expr='isnull', exclude=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
```